# Connecting from Terminal 3 to 1 at Copenhagen CPH

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, short-connections, cph

US citizen traveling into Copenhagen, arriving Terminal 3 at 13:00 and need to connect to a domestic flight at Terminal 1 at 14:45.

Any suggestions on fastest way between terminals?

Will walking be faster than shuttle bus, considering possible wait times for bus?

What about passport control procedures for the connecting flight?

Answer (score 2):

Walking time is estimated to be about 15min (see [overview+timing map](http://www.cph.dk/Images/For-rejsende/F%C3%B8r%20rejsen/Transferpassagerer/walking-distances-map.jpg) and [detailed T2/3 map](http://www.cph.dk/Documents/For%20rejsende/CASC/Transit-Area-Map.pdf)) and suggested transfer times are about 45min ([official times](http://www.cph.dk/en/before-travelling/Transfer-Passengers/Connection-Times/)).

SAS has a page giving info on '[from the US to Copenhagen and onwards](http://www.flysas.com/us/Destinations/Copenhagen/airport/)' which states arriving at T3 there will be screens showing transfer options and times to T1.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply-yes we are definitely arriving in terminal 3